# How to populate the selected dropdown values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

Selected Drop down values are getting NULL but when i try to populate the text i am able to get the values.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Indent No <font class="star_color"> * </font> </label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtindentNo" runat="server" Class="form-control" 
  OnTextChanged="txtindentNo_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Select Item <font class="star_color"> * </font> </label>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItem_SelectedIndexChanged">
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>


  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Indent Number " ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblIndentNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("IndentNumber") %>' Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblItem" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SeedItemNameEng") %>' Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItem" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("SeedItemID") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code:

`txtindentNo.Text = ((Label)grdItems.Rows[IndexValue].FindControl("lblIndentNo")).Text.Trim();

ddlItem.SelectedValue = ((Label)grdItems.Rows[IndexValue].FindControl("lblItem")).Text.Trim();`

Comment: You need to populate ddlItem.SelecteText also...

Comment: Yes i am able to populate  "txtindentNo" in TextBox but i am not able to do in dropdown for "ddlItem".

Comment: Are you populating drop-down using client script? If that is the case you will not get the value of drop-down. This is how .net compiler works. It accepts only those data from non editable controls which is rendered by .net compiler.